# Boost asio Error 10054

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I was testing my program written in C++ client and server.
And it was running allright, suddenly it stops to work, giving me this error code
Error Code: 10054
I don't know what to do to correct it, don't know what is the real problem, already tried a lot of things without success.
Thanks

Comment: From the error code I assume you are using windows. Because 10054 means connection reset by peer. So which program gets this error. The client? Then your sever is dead. The server? Then check your client.

Comment: Yeah, i posted this and them looked how dumb I am, as I was just testing I was closing the connection on client after the write, im trying to see if it is the problem.

Comment: That was the error, a simple Sleep solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Probably your Client is closed and server is writing to a closed client.